# Android: layout padding, margin, spacing attributes and their defaults for different views

Tags: android, layout, margin, padding, spacing

Is there any resource that has all the default margins, paddings, spacings, etc for the different views in the one spot? Like a layout cheat sheet or something. It would be really handy when doing a layout to know the names of the non-zero spacing attributes for each view so you don't need to go searching for them. If not could one of you gurus maybe create one here?